# c++ execute function any time a stream is written to

Tags: c++, events, callback, stringstream

I have a simple GUI program that uses a custom `stringstream` to redirect output from the console to a text field in the GUI (under some circumstances).  currently. the window redraws any time I hit enter, but it's possible that output could be generated at other times.  Is there a way to register a function with the `stringstream` that gets executed every time the `<<` operator is used on the stream?

**NOTE**

I should have pointed out that I cannot use C++11 in my solution.  the machines on which this will be compiled and run will not have c++11 available.

Comment: Can't you just overload this operator?

Comment: @Kylo I hadn't thought about that.  I'm not sure it would work, though, as I want the function to be executed only when THIS string stream is written to, not any stringstream.  can that be done?

Comment: Sure. You've mentioned that you are using custom stringstream. Adam Rosenfield gave you good answer I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't use an `std::ostringstream` (or even an `std::stringstream`) for this at all! Instead, I would create my own stream buffer taking care of sending the data to the GUI. That is, I'd overwrite `std::streambuf::overflow()` and `std::streambuf::sync()` to send the current data to the GUI. To also make sure that any output is sent immediately, I'd set up an `std::ostream` to have `std::ios_base::unitbuf` set. Actually, sending the changes to a function is quite simple, i.e., I'll implement this:

```
#include <streambuf>
#include <ostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream> // only for testing...

#if HAS_FUNCTION
typedef std::function<void(std::string)> function_type;
#else
class function_type
{
private:
    struct base {
        virtual ~base() {}
        virtual base* clone() const = 0;
        virtual void  call(std::string const&) = 0;
    };
    template <typename Function>
    struct concrete
        : base {
        Function d_function;
        concrete(Function function)
            : d_function(function) {
        }
        base* clone() const { return new concrete<Function>(this->d_function); }
        void  call(std::string const& value) { this->d_function(value); }
    };
    std::auto_ptr<base> d_function;
public:
    template <typename Function>
    function_type(Function function)
        : d_function(new concrete<Function>(function)) {
    }
    function_type(function_type const& other)
        : d_function(other.d_function->clone()) {
    }
    function_type& operator= (function_type other) {
        this->swap(other);
        return *this;
    }
    ~function_type() {}
    void swap(function_type& other) {
        std::swap(this->d_function, other.d_function);
    }
    void operator()(std::string const& value) {
        this->d_function->call(value);
    }
};
#endif

class functionbuf
    : public std::streambuf {
private:
    typedef std::streambuf::traits_type traits_type;
    function_type d_function;
    char          d_buffer[1024];
    int overflow(int c) {
        if (!traits_type::eq_int_type(c, traits_type::eof())) {
            *this->pptr() = traits_type::to_char_type(c);
            this->pbump(1);
        }
        return this->sync()? traits_type::not_eof(c): traits_type::eof();
    }
    int sync() {
        if (this->pbase() != this->pptr()) {
            this->d_function(std::string(this->pbase(), this->pptr()));
            this->setp(this->pbase(), this->epptr());
        }
        return 0;
    }
public:
    functionbuf(function_type const& function)
        : d_function(function) {
        this->setp(this->d_buffer, this->d_buffer + sizeof(this->d_buffer) - 1);
    }
};

class ofunctionstream
    : private virtual functionbuf
    , public std::ostream {
public:
    ofunctionstream(function_type const& function)
        : functionbuf(function)
        , std::ostream(static_cast<std::streambuf*>(this)) {
        this->flags(std::ios_base::unitbuf);
    }
};

void some_function(std::string const& value) {
    std::cout << "some_function(" << value << ")\n";
}

int main() {
    ofunctionstream out(&some_function);
    out << "hello" << ',' << " world: " << 42 << "\n";
    out << std::nounitbuf << "not" << " as " << "many" << " calls\n" << std::flush;
}
```

A fair chunk of the above code is actually unrelated to the task at hand: it implements a primitive version of `std::function<void(std::string)>` in case C++2011 can't be used.

If you don't want quite as many calls, you can turn off `std::ios_base::unitbuf` and only sent the data upon flushing the stream, e.g. using `std::flush` (yes, I know about `std::endl` but it unfortunately is typically misused to I strongly recommend to get rid of it and use `std::flush` where a flush is really meant).

Comment: Thanks.  However, I should have pointed out that I cannot use c++11.  The machines on which this will be compiled and run will not have it.

Comment: That's not really a major issue: the only use of C++ 2011 is the use of `std::function<void(std::string)>`. One simple remedy is to use `boost::function<void(std::string)>` instead. If this isn't an option either it is fairly straight forward to create a simple class with the same logic for one argument (it just become painful when needing more arguments).

Comment: can you give me a compile command for that?  how do I link the boost libraries?

Comment: I have updated the code to implement a simple version of `std::function<void(std::string)>` directly. All you need to do is build the code and, if you do have a C++ 2011 compiler, defined the macro `HAS_FUNCTION` (e.g. using `-DHAS_FUNCTION` on the command line).

Answer (score 4):

In order to do this you should create your own streambuf class. streambuf classes represent IO devices and each one takes care of the various issues specific to that kind of device. The standard defines a streambuf for files and another for strings. Network access would use another, and output to a GUI should also be represented as another kind of device if you're going to use streams at all.

Writing an appropriate streambuf class isn't trivial and seems to be kind obscure, but there are resources out there. *[The C++ Standard Library - A Tutorial and Reference](http://www.cppstdlib.com/)* has a small section on this. *[Standard C++ IOStreams and Locales: Advanced Programmer's Guide and Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201183951)* provides in-depth information. A search for `subclassing basic_streambuf` will also turn up some free resources online.

Comment: Hm. I can't understand why people think that writing a stream buffer is obscure at all! It is a class like any other and the interface isn't really that complicated. Except for a few simple typos I managed to implement the code in just a few minutes! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, can you derive a subclass from stringstream and overload its stream insertion operator to generate events?

Pseudocode:

```
class AlertingStream : public stringstream
{
    ostream& operator << (type)
    {
        for (each listener in listeners)
        {
            listener.notify();
        }
        perform insertion;
        return *this;
    }
}
```