# Capturing and raising events on std::cout flush events

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream

I'm trying to write a scoped object to redirect output from `std::cout` and call a function when it's underlying buffer is flushed.

My implementation borrows heavily from the following SO answer:

[c++ execute function any time a stream is written to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826751/c-execute-function-any-time-a-stream-is-written-to)

I have it partially working, but the callback function is only called when I explicity call `flush` on `std::cout`. However, I want it to call the callback function whenever *anything* is written to the stream.

**NOTE**: I am compiling aginst MSVC++11.

```
struct stream_redirect
{
    stream_redirect(std::ostream& stream, std::streambuf* rdbuf) :
        stream(stream),
        rdbuf_old(stream.rdbuf())
    {
        stream.set_rdbuf(rdbuf);
    }

    ~stream_redirect()
    {
        stream.set_rdbuf(rdbuf_old);
    }

private:
    stream_redirect(const stream_redirect&) = delete;
    stream_redirect& operator = (const stream_redirect&) = delete;

    std::ostream& stream;
    std::streambuf* rdbuf_old;
};

struct functionbuf : public std::streambuf
{
    typedef std::function<void(std::string)> function_type;

    functionbuf(const function_type& function)
        : function(function)
    {
        setp(buffer, buffer + sizeof(buffer) - 1);
    }

private:
    char buffer[1024];
    function_type function;

    virtual int_type overflow(int_type c) override
    {
        if (!traits_type::eq_int_type(c, traits_type::eof()))
        {
            *this->pptr() = traits_type::to_char_type(c);
            pbump(1);
        }

        return sync() ? traits_type::not_eof(c) : traits_type::eof();
    }

    virtual int_type sync() override
    {
        if (pbase() != pptr())
        {
            function(std::string(pbase(), pptr()));

            setp(pbase(), epptr());
        }

        return 0;
    }
};

struct ofunctionstream :
    private virtual functionbuf,
    public std::ostream
{
    ofunctionstream(const function_type& function) :
        functionbuf(function),
        std::ostream(static_cast<std::streambuf*>(this))
    {
        setf(std::ios_base::unitbuf);
    }
};
```

Now a usage example:

```
void callback(std::string string)
{
    printf("callback(%s)\n", string.c_str());
}

int main()
{
    ofunctionstream fs(&callback);
    stream_redirect sr(std::cout, fs.rdbuf());

    printf("sending string to cout...");
    std::cout << "hello!";
    printf("string sent to cout");

    //this is necessary to 
    printf("flushing cout...");
    std::cout.flush();
    printf("cout flushed");
}
```

I get the following output:

```
sending string to cout...
string sent to cout
flushing cout...
callback(hello!)
cout flushed
```

Again, I want that callback function to be called as soon as `std::cout << "hello!";` is called.  I assumed this would happen since I am calling `setf(std::ios_base::unitbuf)` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/unitbuf) on the `ofunctionstream` object in it's constructor.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you examine how the callback that you're using works, it works by subclassing `std::streambuf` and by overriding `overflow()`. That's important to note.

Quoting the relevant parts of the C++ standard library:

> 27.6.3.2.5 Put area                        [streambuf.pub.put]
>
> int_type sputc(char_type c);
>
> Returns: If the output sequence write position is not available,
>   returns overflow(traits::to_int_- type(c)). Otherwise, stores c at the
>   next pointer for the output sequence, increments the pointer, and
>   returns traits::to_int_type(c)

`std::ostream`, a.k.a. formatted output, writes to the stream buffer using sputc(). So, the only time `overflow()` gets invoked is when the output buffer is exhausted. Or explicitly via `std::flush`.

So, your options are, unfortunately, somewhat limited. Either deal with the current behavior, or jury-rig the `std::streambuf` subclass to have no write buffer at all, so that *every* character that ends up getting written via `sputc()` is going to get punted to `overflow()`, and invoke your subclass implementation.

Unfortunately, stream operations do not carry out any explicit action after every formatting operation, that can be intercepted by the `std::streambuf`. They just write the formatted output, one character at a time, via `sputc()`, so that the output gets collected in the streambuf's write buffer, which gets flushed out only when it's full, or when `std::flush` gets explicitly used.

So, that's how it works.